# Why was Japanese Unit 731 immune from War Crime trials?

Tags: world-war-two

Question about WWII; I came across Unit 731, and was wondering why the US had the authority/right to grant Japanese Unit 731 immunity from war crime trials, in exchange for the human experimentation results (just to the US but not other allies)?

Also - I'm researching more - but from what I've read, so far, it seems like the post-war treatments Japan received were softer in a degree compared to that of Germany? For instance, Japan was free from trials whilst the Nuremberg and Doctor's trials were aimed at the Nazis.

Comment: It was a decision of Douglas McArthur

Comment: and why did he decide that though?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Military_Tribunal_for_the_Far_East

Comment: Felix, thank for the link, i had no idea about that.  Its pretty sad to me they were given immunity solely for their data on human experimentation.  Was the data that valuable that it excused the units horrible crimes?

Comment: At least one author has argued that the data was basically worthless but its value was exaggerated for political reasons: http://ahrp.org/scholarly-analyses-confirm-u-s-complicity-in-creating-a-sense-of-collective-amnesia/ 

Here is more detailed discussion of this question from Reddit... I haven't combed through it but there seems to be some helpful sources cited here and there: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/1xd0yz/why_did_the_us_give_immunity_to_japanese/

Comment: Maybe the big picture is more important here: japan had de facto immunity in many war crimes partly because the US needed some kind of cooperation with Japan, and didn't want to push these issues too much. For example many post war Japanese government members were active high profile politicians during the war: that was very unlike in European Axis countries.

Comment: @Greg If that were the case, the US would have spared the civilian leaders who merely failed to stop the militarism. You'd have to remove many, many rungs of far more harmless politicians and bureaucrats, before you reach these human experimenting war criminals. From the perspective of securing post-war Japan's cooperation, sparing Unit 731 really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Semaphore all those innocent Japanese civilians who felt victim of unjust international tribunals.. oh, you mean the generals who war appointed by navy and army to a government, and lead nation to war, so at the end they can be fall men to cover for Hirohito?

Comment: Maybe the fact that the Unit was established on the order of Hirohito also explains why MacArthur didn’t want to bring it up on trial. It would hard to call Hirohito innocent...

Comment: @Greg Generals and admirals are by definition military leaders. *I explicitly said **"civilian leaders"** precisely because I am **not** talking about the generals.* If you can't engage in good faith without sanctimonious strawmans, then there's no room for discussions here.

Comment: Japan was not free from trials. You question is based on a false premise.

Comment: @Semaphore Any kind of leader is a non-civilian leader, per definition, in a military government lead country where political opposition was strictly suppressed by secret service, military and all kind of shady methods.

Comment: @Greg Now you're just making up your own definitions to paper over gaps in knowledge. Evidently your whole concern is to paint me as some kind of history revisionist, rather than acknowledge the logic of my argument that Unit 731 was useless for "cooperation" relative to the 250,000+ politicians and bureaucrats the US punished, who never engaged in anything as heinous as human experimentation. It should also be obvious, if you were objective, that saying Unit 731 was worse than some of the punished people does *not* imply that everyone or anyone punished were "innocent".

Comment: Japanese leaders were tried for crimes against peace, i.e. waging aggressive war, and (under the principle of command responsibility) for war crimes against POWs and against civilians in occupied territories. There was no particular distinction in the Tokyo trial between civilian and military leaders.

Answer (score 7):

The Soviet Union tried Japanese in Khabarovsk for the Unit 731 atrocities. And the US decision was not to prosecute, rather than to grant immunity (it's a legal quibble, but nonetheless important). The general rule was that each Allied power could prosecute Japanese for war crimes if they held them. There was a significant 'trade' in Japanese accused among the various Allied powers for this purpose.

Comment: Good first answer, if you could point out a few sources for people to read that would make it even better.

Comment: Wilson et al., Japanese War Criminals is a good start.